Handling access to multiple resources with expo-auth-session
I've been attempting to retrieve multiple accessTokens for communication with both the Microsoft graph API and my API. If I understand this correctly I need a token for each resource, with the correct scopes related to the resource I'm trying to connect to. My team decided to use expo-auth-session to handle this for our react-native application. Getting the first token works fine where the user is prompted with the Microsoft login page, but the seconds request also requires the user to consent. I've tried figuring out how I can avoid having the second prompt without luck. Here's my code:
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { exchangeCodeAsync, makeRedirectUri, Prompt, useAuthRequest, useAutoDiscovery } from 'expo-auth-session';
import { ProfileContext } from '../context/ProfileContext';
import { useQueryClient } from '@tanstack/react-query';

const useAuthentication = () => {
    const TENANT_ID = '<MY_TENANT_ID>';
    const CLIENT_ID = '<MY_CLIENT_ID>';
    const AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0`;
    const TOKEN_ENDPOINT = `${AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT}/token`;
    const LOGIN_ENDPOINT = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${TENANT_ID}/v2.0`;
    const LOGOUT_ENDPOINT = `${AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT}/logout`;

    const SCOPES_GRAPH = ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'offline_access'];
    const SCOPES_MY_API = [`${CLIENT_ID}/.default`];

    const queryClient = useQueryClient();
    const {
        accessToken,
        idToken,
        setAccessToken,
        setIdToken,
        myApiAccessToken,
        setMyApiAccessToken,
    } = useContext(ProfileContext);

    const discovery = useAutoDiscovery(LOGIN_ENDPOINT);
    const redirectUri = makeRedirectUri({
        scheme: undefined,
        path: 'auth',
    });
    const clientId = CLIENT_ID;
    const [request, , promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
        {
            clientId,
            scopes: SCOPES_GRAPH,
            redirectUri,
            extraParams: {
                prompt: Prompt.SelectAccount,
            },
        },
        discovery,
    );

    const login = async () => {
        promptAsync().then(async (codeResponse) => {
            if (request && codeResponse?.type === 'success' && discovery) {
                await exchangeCodeAsync(
                    {
                        clientId,
                        code: codeResponse.params.code,
                        extraParams: request.codeVerifier
                            ? { code_verifier: request.codeVerifier }
                            : undefined,
                        redirectUri,
                    },
                    discovery,
                ).then(async (res) => {
                    setAccessToken(res.accessToken);
                    await fetchSecondToken();
                });
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('Failed to login:', error);
        });
    };

    const [myApiRequest, , myApiPromptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
        {
            clientId,
            prompt: Prompt.None,
            scopes: SCOPES_MY_API,
            redirectUri,
        },
        discovery,
    );

    const fetchSecondToken = async () => {
        if (!discovery || !myApiRequest) return;

        await myApiPromptAsync().then((codeResponse) => {
            if (request && codeResponse?.type === 'success' && discovery) {
                exchangeCodeAsync(
                    {
                        clientId,
                        code: codeResponse.params.code,
                        extraParams: request.codeVerifier
                            ? { code_verifier: request.codeVerifier }
                            : undefined,
                        redirectUri,
                    },
                    discovery,
                ).then((res) => {
                    setMyApiAccessToken(res.accessToken);
                });
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('Failed to login:', error);
        });
    };

    return { login };
};

export default useAuthentication;

I am lost as to how to make this work, so I've started to read the Oauth2 spec..
I have set the Prompt to none, as I already have asked for consent to begin with. I suspect there's something about informing about the first authentication result in the second request, but I can't quite find out how using the expo documentation https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session/
